# git filter-branch --tree-filter left me with 2x commit objects

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I did this:

```bash
git filter-branch --tree-filter '~/fix-lines.sh' -d /dev/shm/repo-temp \
--tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all
```

Basically fixing some line ending issues.  (some 793 commits were rewritten).  Then I realized hey, I might as well convert my tabs to 4 spaces.  So I did this:

```bash
git filter-branch --tree-filter '~/fix-tabs.sh' -d /dev/shm/repo-temp \
--tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all
```

Now I am going through 1594 commit objects (some new were added).

Apparently my entire old tree is still somewhere in git repo?  If so, how do I get rid of it and how do I check that it is gone?  I only want to keep the "original" rewritten ~800 commits, and no more.

Comment: I think I know why -- I have tags that are immutable and they probably prevent git gc from collecting the trees.....  Well .. I need to somehow re-tag the trees, or remove the tags, so those trees can be collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for tags you may have created that may keep the old tree from being garbage-collected.
Namely, git-filter-branch leaves tags on the original tree untouched and does not auto-move them to the new tree.

To get rid of it I did things like

```
git push . :refs/original/refs/tags/v1.0.x
git push origin :refs/original/refs/tags/v1.0.5
```

until all original and extra tags were gone

Comment: It's too bad most other mentions of this command don't talk about removing tags first.